# I'm getting a error when I declare a class as a member of other class. error : a class-key must be used when declaring a friend

Tags: c++, class, boost-serialization

I am a C++ rookie and I was experimenting with boost serialization and I wanted to see if it works when a class is declared as a member of another class. But when I compile my code I get loads of errors. I tried declaring baseds as a struct but no change in errors. My code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

class baseds{};
class superior{};

class baseds {
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    baseds(){}
    ~baseds(){}
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & a;
        ar & b;
        ar & c;
    }
};

class superior  {
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    baseds lag;
    superior(){}
    ~superior(){}
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & x;
        ar & y;
        ar & lag;
    }
};

int main()  {

    superior myData,myData2;
    myData.x=10;
    myData.y=20;
    myData.lag.a=1;
    myData.lag.b=2;
    myData.lag.c=3;

    ofstream ofs("steps.txt");
    {
        boost::serialization::archive one(ofs);
        one << myData;
    }

    ifstream ifs("steps.txt");
    {
        boost::serialization::archive two(ifs);
        two >> myData2;
    }
    std::cout<<"\n"<<myData2.x;
    std::cout<<"\n"<<myData2.y;
    std::cout<<"\n"<<myData2.lag.a;
    std::cout<<"\n"<<myData2.lag.b;
    std::cout<<"\n"<<myData2.lag.c;

    return 0;

}
```

errors:

```
tier2.cpp:10: error: a class-key must be used when declaring a friend
tier2.cpp:29: error: a class-key must be used when declaring a friend
tier2.cpp:32: error: expected `;' before "int"
tier2.cpp: In member function `void superior::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int)':
tier2.cpp:38: error: `x' undeclared (first use this function)
tier2.cpp:38: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
tier2.cpp:39: error: `y' undeclared (first use this function)
tier2.cpp:40: error: `lag' undeclared (first use this function)
tier2.cpp: In function `int main()':
tier2.cpp:47: error: 'class superior' has no member named 'x'
tier2.cpp:48: error: 'class superior' has no member named 'y'
tier2.cpp:49: error: 'class superior' has no member named 'lag'
tier2.cpp:50: error: 'class superior' has no member named 'lag'
tier2.cpp:51: error: 'class superior' has no member named 'lag'
tier2.cpp:53: error: `ofstream' undeclared (first use this function)
tier2.cpp:53: error: expected `;' before "ofs"
tier2.cpp:55: error: `archive' is not a member of `boost::serialization'
tier2.cpp:55: error: expected `;' before "one"
tier2.cpp:56: error: `one' undeclared (first use this function)
tier2.cpp:57: error: expected `;' before '}' token
tier2.cpp:59: error: `ifstream' undeclared (first use this function)
tier2.cpp:59: error: expected `;' before "ifs"
tier2.cpp:61: error: `archive' is not a member of `boost::serialization'
tier2.cpp:61: error: expected `;' before "ones"
tier2.cpp:62: error: `ones' undeclared (first use this function)
tier2.cpp:63: error: expected `;' before '}' token
tier2.cpp:64: error: 'class superior' has no member named 'x'
tier2.cpp:65: error: 'class superior' has no member named 'y'
tier2.cpp:66: error: 'class superior' has no member named 'lag'
tier2.cpp:67: error: 'class superior' has no member named 'lag'
tier2.cpp:68: error: 'class superior' has no member named 'lag'
tier2.cpp:71:2: warning: no newline at end of file
```

Comment: I don't know anything about serialization. Why do you have class baseds{}; class superior{}; before the actual class definition?

Comment: To expand on sajas' comment, `class baseds;` is a class forward declaration, `class baseds{};` is a definition. Technically you're redefining `baseds` and `superior`.

Answer (score 1):

You are re-defining both `baseds` and `superior`. You should get an error similar to

```
class baseds{};   // definition
class superior{}; // definition

// second definition
class baseds {
private:
 ....
```

> error: redefinition of 'class baseds'

Remove the first pair of definitions.

Comment: Or turn them into declarations by removing the braces only.

Comment: @SebastianRedl There would be no point in having those declarations though :)

Comment: Not in the example, but they might be necessary in the original code. Or they might be a style preference; I've seen codebases where a file starts with declarations of the classes it defines (e.g. MFC).

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `baseds` and `superior` twice.

On gcc you would get the proper error message:

```
main.cpp:9:7: error: redefinition of 'baseds'
class baseds {
      ^
main.cpp:6:7: note: previous definition is here
class baseds{};
      ^
main.cpp:27:7: error: redefinition of 'superior'
class superior  {
      ^
main.cpp:7:7: note: previous definition is here
class superior{};
```

Seemingly your compiler does not recognize the redefinition and gets lost, producing the poor error message.

If you meant to provide a forward declaration of both classes, you need to lose the braces:

```
class baseds;
class superior;

class baseds {
  /* ... */
};
```

But sice you don't use `superior` for the definition of `baseds` at all, you can leave out the forward declarations completely - for the definition of `superior` you need the *definition* of `baseds`, since you have a member of that type and therefore a forward declaration is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry fellow stackoverflow citizens, this was a stupid question, figured out most of the errors after a good sleep
The correct code is as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

class baseds;
class superior;

class baseds {
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    baseds(){}
    ~baseds(){}
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & a;
        ar & b;
        ar & c;
    }
};

class superior  {
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend class baseds;
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    baseds lag;
    superior(){}
    ~superior(){}
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & x;
        ar & y;
        ar & lag;
    }
};

int main()  {

    superior myData,myData2;
    myData.x=10;
    myData.y=20;
    myData.lag.a=1;
    myData.lag.b=2;
    myData.lag.c=3;

    std::ofstream ofs("steps.txt");
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive one(ofs);
        one << myData;
    }

    std::ifstream ifs("steps.txt");
    {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive two(ifs);
        two >> myData2;
    }
    std::cout<<"\n"<<myData2.x;
    std::cout<<"\n"<<myData2.y;
    std::cout<<"\n"<<myData2.lag.a;
    std::cout<<"\n"<<myData2.lag.b;
    std::cout<<"\n"<<myData2.lag.c;

    return 0;

}
```